# Arquillian in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, jboss-arquillian

Anyone know how i can use arquillian in maven netbeans project?. I have already tried to create a project in netbeans and use this dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but i's error, the message error in netbeans tell me that in `arquillian-junit-container` didn't have a version tag. This dependency was copied from arquillian website. sorry for my bad english

Comment: You have not copied the full dependcy from the website. Please copy the dependency for Bom file also or specify the version of junit container